Problem with State Transition Matrix Derivation
I am concerned with the problem
$$x'(t) = A(t)x(t),$$
where $x(t)$ and $x'(t)$ are column vectors and $A(t)$ is a matrix. The system has the initial conditions $x(t_0)= x_0$ and I suppose that $\phi(t;t_0,x_0)$ is a solution to this system. Then with n linearly independent solutions, ${\phi_1 ... \phi_n}$ I have
$$ \phi(t;t_0,x_0) = c_1\phi(t;t_0,x_1)  + ...+c_n\phi(t;t_0,x_n) $$
for arbitrary coefficients. Then I define $\Phi(t;t_0,X_0) = [\phi(t;t_0,x_1) ... \phi(t;t_0,x_n)]$, $C = [c_1 ... c_n]^T$ and $ X_0 = [x_1 ... x_n]$ to have the following equality.
$$ \phi(t;t_0,x_0) = \Phi(t;t_0,X_0)C.$$ Also, $x_0 = c_1x_1 +...+c_nx_n = X_0C$ and assuming $X_0$ is the identity matrix, $I$, I obtain the following expression
$$ \phi(t;t_0,x_0) = \Phi(t;t_0,I)I^{-1}x_0 = \Phi(t;t_0)x_0. $$ From this I cannot see how I can further show that
$$  \Phi(t;t_0,X_0) = \Phi(t;t_0)X_0. $$ So I need help to see how the last equality holds. Thank you.

Seems like a textbook proof, did you check out textbooks?

I took it from my lecture notes, and unfortunately, the textbook I have does not have this and I cannot piece together the above steps to reach the last step.
